# Link error on IIS7 after a migration from Apache

Tags: php, mysql, apache, iis-7

I migrated a PHP application from Apache to IIS7, all the links are loaded from a MySQL table record that contains the path directory. I have the same structure in my PHP code as well as in MySQL db. However, the PHP code doesn't execute when I click the links, it only works on my home page. I get the following error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found 
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Is this an IIS configuration problem?

> This is for the home page:

```
<ul>                  
<?php
echo $class->menu->topmenu( $patharray[0] ) ?>                                        
</ul>
```

> The following is for the link:

```
function topmenu ( $path = 'home' )
    {
        $home = $this->fetchOne ( $this->query( "SELECT * FROM admin_menu WHERE parent = 0" ) ) ;
        $links = $this->fetch ( $this->query ( "SELECT admin_menu.*, aus.value FROM admin_menu LEFT JOIN admin_user_status aus ON ( aus.id = admin_menu.status ) WHERE parent = 1 AND active ='yes'  ORDER BY sort ASC" ) ) ;

        if ( $links )
            foreach ( $links as $key => $link )
            {

                if ( $key == 0)
                    $url = '/';


                else 
                    $url = $link->url;

                //if ( $link->priv == 'open' || ( $link->priv == 'private' && $this->userinfo->status == 225 ) )
                if( $this->check_user_priv( $link ) )
                {
                    if( stripos( $link->url, $path ) === false )
                        $result .= "<li class='mainlevel'><a href='$url'  >$link->text</a></li>" ;
                    else 
                        $result .= "<li class='mainlevel'><b><a href='$url'  >$link->text</a></b></li>" ;
                }


            }


return $result; 
}
```

> The url links above are loaded from the table, but when I click on them I get the 
>   HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.

Comment: Impossible to give an answer without the slightest hint about files, layout and links.

Comment: We are going to need to see some examples of the links and the code that creates them.

Comment: They are just text like: [Home] - [User] - [Status] So, when I click on status which is: status.php it doesn't execute.

Comment: @Jacman Have you checked the generated page code on browser?

Comment: @Ertunc thanks for your answer ...Yes, they're going to the right path, if that's what you mean.

Comment: They're hardly going to the right path if the result is a 404, are they? Can you show some real world examples of URLs that the links point to?

Comment: This is what I get for most likely causes: -The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
-The URL contains a typographical error.
-A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I solved my problem by importing Apache mod_rewrite Rules into the URL Rewrite Module in IIS 7. My migration from Apache had .htaccess rules that needed to be converted for the web.config. I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: this got me on the right track, thanks.  here's where you can download URL Rewrite for IIS 7: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module